# Returning JSON from PHP, convert JSON to javascript array, return array from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, json

I am working on a project that uses a function I called AjaxRequest which handles all AJAX requests I make. I have no problems in making the request however getting the request back is the issue and placing it where I want it on my page is becoming stressful.

HTML BIT

```
<body onLoad="calling();">
<div id="status">Status: </div>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT BIT

```
function calling() {
    var answer = ajaxRequest("testing", "test.php", "test=test");

    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML += answer[1];
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML += " " + answer[3];
}

function ajaxRequest(app, location, credentials) {  
var extras = ""; 
if(credentials === "" || credentials) { 
        extras = "&" + credentials; 
    }

    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", location);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
            var arrayObj = [];
            for(var i in obj) { arrayObj.push([i, obj[i]]); }
            return arrayObj;
        }
    }
    ajax.send("app=" + app + extras); 
}
```

there are two other functions running: ajaxObj and ajaxReturn but I excluded those because they is not the problem. Furthermore, I am trying to make ajaxRequest an efficient function that could be used by more than one application without having to rewrite all the code in more than one location. All error handling acquires before the actual use of ajaxRequest.

PHP BIT

```
<?php
if($_POST['app'] == "testing") {
    $hey = array('success' => 1, 'message' => 'Successful');
    echo json_encode($hey);
    exit();
}
?>
```

I'm using calling as a javascript function that does all error handling, this is just basic for the whole of my project however I try to get the JSON from php and convert it to array and the issue is returning the array into calling. I try to display the information on the page yet nothing works.

I am not looking to use any JQuery for my project so I would like to exclude the use of it for this piece of code.

Comment: (1) What do you expect the value of `answer` to be immediately after `var answer = ajaxRequest("testing", "test.php", "test=test");`? (2) Do you know that the first A in 'AJAX' stands for aynchronous?

Comment: I expect answer to be an array that I can access all of its information that is returned. I am aware of the asynchronous works of it, however I need a function that does the requests I need and all other bits I can add to the function later.

Comment: Where in `ajaxRequest` is the `return` statement which would yield that array?

Comment: My main goal at the moment is to get an array back from ajaxRequest and this array I want it to have success equal to either 0 or 1, next I want a message which can be optional depending on the application in question.

Comment: that is the return value of the function you assign to `ajax.onreadyStateChange`, it is not the return value of `ajaxRequest', which does not return anything.

Comment: If you're doing the request Synchronously, i.e. _not_ Asynchronously, then you will be able to return a value from your ajaxRequest function.  If you're not, then you will need to use a callback function, inside of which you would put your `innerHTML` assignments, using the server's response.  In Synchronous requests, everything halts and waits for the server to respond, which is why a return value from the server is possible.  In Asynchronous requests, the script does not halt, so you have to define a callback function to handle the server's response, once it arrives.

Comment: (3) What happens if you insert this `alert(answer);` immediately after `var answer = ajaxRequest("testing", "test.php", "test=test");`?  If I've understood the problem correctly, you will see a popup saying 'undefined'.

Comment: then something along the lines of me getting the request, placing it in a variable and then packaging it out of the ajax.onreadyStateChange portion, is that possible? I might not fully understand AJAX the way I should have. my goal is to make the requst, get an answer, return the answer to the function that originally called it. Then I'm assuming I should send more information into the function ajaxRequest?

Comment: and yeah I get undefined. I have been unsettled with that for few days. Now I am starting to understand what I did wrong.

Comment: Is jQuery not an option?

Comment: not really, this is something I'm trying to avoid for a lot of reasons, however I might work on a jQuery equivalent at some point later in the future. idk I will see about it later. At this point I am trying to understand my mistakes and learn from them. This project is best at pushing me to my limits and I must admit the challenge is making me smile a lot but I have yet to fully understand everything about my own work.

Comment: At least I made progress. I put the arrayObj out of the ajax.onreadystatechange and then pushed the information into the array once I got a response. It returned to my calling two undefined answers however i feel I'm closer to the answer.

Comment: am I converting the JSON to an array by any chance? I believe im converting it incorrectly

Comment: I got my solution. I will work on my ajaxRequest and make it do exactly what I want it to do in order to make it work from the ajax itself and not outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you could set the header before sending back the json.

header('Content-Type: application/json');

Usually you don't need it, but it will tell your javascript that it's json, and the array will be transform in a javascript object. It work with Jquery, but I assume it'll work without too

Comment: I am using headers and they are located in my ajaxObj function that I did not display, want me to display it?

Comment: What I'm saying is you should tell it from php to. That way, when it get send to the browser, the browser will know it's json

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had not seen it sense today. I implemented what you recommended